# Stying the Form element using Jquery - OnClick event does not capture it

Tags: jquery, forms

I am using below below to styling my checkbox and Radio button.

http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/

After i incorporate it, onclick event in the checkbox unable to capture it,

```
 <div class="checkbox" style="background-position: 50% 0px; ">
<input type="checkbox" value="Corn Salsa" name="toppings[]" onClick="showmsg()"></div>



//javascript code
function showmsg()
{
alert("yes its working");
}
```

i am sure i dont have any errors in javascript, because when i tried in firebug error console it does not thrown any error, but i understand that onclick event is not even captured. :(

is that because DIV tag masking the checkbox? can you guide me  how i can capture the onclick for the checkboxes?

Edit:
 oh no, i just gave this script as example..

but my issue is not this one :D , i am sorry ab , check out the below url , you can see i have used jquery plugin to style the checkbox, but onclick function does not invoking it.

http://goo.gl/eGxYL

look at the above url ,

you can see the working

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
         function showmsg()
            {
            alert("yes its working">
            }
</script>
```

is wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
         function showmsg()
            {
            alert("yes its working");
            }
</script>
```

is correct.

Other than that, the code should work. Javascript onClick event doesnt bother about DOM under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/y7TZW/

Typo error: `)` instead of `>` :)

recommendation: have you thought of using `.click` event? like this http://jsfiddle.net/y7TZW/1/ (this will save onClick event in all your checkboxes) just a suggesstion.

API click : http://jsfiddle.net/y7TZW/1/

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//javascript code
function showmsg() { 
    alert("yes its working"); 
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Both of us assumed initially that he had used `<script>` tags.  But considering that he hasn't found any javascript errors for that obvious  mistake, i don't think that he had the script tags. lol.

Comment: @ngen lol in the **demo** I have inserted the script tag :) http://jsfiddle.net/y7TZW/ ; I did considered that but was waiting for the OP to ask :P

Comment: no , not actually :D my issue is different.. i just updated my question.

Comment: @PHPLearner No worries! can you please make a jsfiddle to replicate your problem? I am very hesitant to click on any external url I am not confident with. cheers